# How to call C# from JScript.net?

Tags: c#, jscript.net

I read that, for the newest Java, Javascript on Java can call or import java packages easily. In the newest .NET, can JScript.net call C# functions easily?

For details, I am asking not about compiled JScript.net code, but about non-compiled JScript.net string code which is run on the script engine.

Comment: is this Javascript or JScript ? Is this with Asp.net ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkx7dfw1.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to call the c# function from javascript

Comment: Are you trying to do this new JScriptCodeProvider().CreateCompiler(); as stated here: http://odetocode.com/code/80.aspx

Comment: @COLDTOLD Yes,because I do not like writing similar functions in javascript again.

Comment: @DmitrySavy I think my problem is same as or similar to your information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example:

1) CS file with a simple calls and method that returns a string.
2) js file that calls the CS method using eval.

// cstest.cs - compile as library

```
using System;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar()
        {
            return "Hello JS";
        }
    }
}
```

// test.js - compile as exe
// add a reference to cstest.dll
// command line compile jsc /t:exe /r:cstest.dll test.js

```
import MyNamespace;

var o : JSApp = new JSApp();
o.DoEval();

class JSApp
{
    function DoEval()
    {
        var f : Foo;
        var s : String
       eval("f = new Foo;");
       eval("s = f.Bar();"); // call Foo.Bar
       print(s);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to to is to convert your JScript.NET code to C#. Something [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4040/Converting-JScript-NET-to-C).

Comment: There is a new version of JScript.NET in Visual Studio 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkx7dfw1.aspx. I'm guessing there's a way to call C# code from JScript.NET, provided you compile your C# code into a .NET DLL and reference it from JScript.NET.