# How to create thumbnails using Adobe bridge with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, adobe-bridge

Is there any way to communicate with Adobe bridge using C# console application?.

I want to create thumbnails for given Image folder (ex:SamplePictures) using bridge..

I know that Bridge support java script,Is there any way  to program with the JavaScript  to Bridge..

Comment: have you done a google search on the topic..? http://www.ehow.com/how_6602850_create-thumbnails-adobe-bridge.html

Comment: i want same feature using C# is there any dll.. which supports Bridge in C#?

Comment: maybe this site will help - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/bridge.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process:

- Run Bridge SDK
- Find method to create thumbnail
- Call method via JScript
- Call C# from JScript

**References**

- [Adobe Photoshop JavaScript Scripting Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_scriptref_js.pdf)
- [How to call C# from JScript.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471332/how-to-call-c-sharp-from-jscript-net)
- [Developing Applications using Inter-Application Communication](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_developer_guide.pdf)
- [How does the C# compiler detect COM types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-detect-com-types)
- [Using a COM dll from C# without a type library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037786/using-a-com-dll-from-c-sharp-without-a-type-library)

Answer (score -1):

The only way to program Bridge is to use BridgeTalk via com using any of Adobe's products that have com, Photoshop, Indesign, Illustrator, etc.
Here is an example of getting a list of selected Bridge files.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace Bridge
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application"));

            //Get list of select files from Bridge
            String Code = "var fileList;" +
            "var bt = new BridgeTalk();" +
            "bt.target = 'bridge';" +
            "bt.body = 'var theFiles = photoshop.getBridgeFileListForAutomateCommand();theFiles.toSource();';" +
            "bt.onResult = function( inBT ) { fileList = eval( inBT.body ); }" +
            "bt.onError = function( inBT ) { fileList = new Array(); }" +
            "bt.send(8);" +
            "if ( undefined == fileList ) {" +
            "fileList = new Array();}" +
            "fileList = decodeURI(fileList.toString());";

            String RC = app.DoJavaScript(Code, null, null);
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.AddRange(RC.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
            for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```